# Scrollable Div inside iframe on iOS Keeps Scrolling to Top

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

I am currently working on an app that is rendered into an iframe on an iOS app and when I scroll a scrollable div inside the iframe the screen flashes a bit when scrolling down then jumps back to the top when I stop scrolling. Right now I am only seeing the issue when this is rendered in the iOS app which was released May 2017, the issue does not happen in iframe in Safari for iOS 11 so I'm guessing whatever issues iOS had with iframes is not an issue in newer versions.

I do not know exactly which version of iOS the app was built for but I believe it is iOS 10.1 or later since the CSS Grid stuff in our app works and it looks like that version added support for CSS Grid, ([Safari 10.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html)), but I'm guessing it could also be iOS 10.3 since caniuse.com suggests that is when iOS supported CSS Grid [Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid)

I've read articles that mention adding a wrapper to the iframe to fix this issue but I don't have control of anything outside of the iframe.

```css
.iframe-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I have added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to my scrollable divs which improved scrolling in the browser but I am unable to fix this issue when it is rendered in the iOS app.

I saw that someone else had the exact same issue but unfortunately no one was able to provide a solution [html - Iframe jumping to the top on iPhone - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351205/iframe-jumping-to-the-top-on-iphone)

Comment: I have this exact problem! Have you had any luck since then in solving it?